# Why is appended svg not positioned at 0,0?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a scale created with D3 and then I pull in an svg sprite using d3.xml. Why is the sprite not in the top left hand corner of the svg before translation? is there a way to ensure the sprite is appended too the exact top left of the SVG?

```
d3.csv('planets.csv').then(function(data){

  var margin = {   top: window.innerHeight * 0.3,   left: 170,   bottom: window.innerHeight * 0.3,   right: 50 };
  var height = (window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom)*0.5;
  var chartWidth = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var maxDist = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.distance; });
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, maxDist]).range([0, chartWidth]);

  var xAxisTop = d3.axisTop(xScale);
    var svg = d3.select('#vis')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', chartWidth + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'chart')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', '+ margin.top +  ')');
      var xAxisDrawTop = svg.insert('g',':first-child')
                               .attr('class','x_axis_top')
                               .call(xAxisTop);

var xAxisDrawTopTorchContainer = d3.select('.x_axis_top').append('g').attr('class','rocket_container')

d3.xml('torch.svg').then(torch=>{

  torchSprite = torch.documentElement;
    xAxisDrawTopTorchContainer.node().append(torchSprite);
  })
```

Comment: We'd have to see what torch.svg is to answer this question.

Comment: Your DOM tree looks like `svg > g.chart > g.x_axis_top > g.rocket_container` where the transformation is on `g.chart`. When appending your sprite to `g.x_axis_top` this happens in the coordinate system **after** the transform of the parent `g` element which is the reason why your sprite is also affected by the transformation.

Comment: I probably did not explain myself fully as the method of using d3.xml to append a sprite causes positioning issues.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to avoid creating a document fragment by using:

```
 d3.select('relevant-g element').append('image').attr('type','image/svg+xml').attr('xlink:href','torch.svg');
```

this ensures the appended sprite is mapped to the coordinates 0,0 of the existing SVG in the DOM.